# Black 2x4 curved top piece of assembly

Tags: piece-information

This piece does not have an identification number on it. It appears to be part of a larger assembly. At each side are two 'legs', neither of which have stud receptacles, so it doesn't hook on to studs.

I'm guessing it slides down inside something as a top piece.

Can someone tell me what element it is?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you don't ask what that element is, but I'm guessing that's what you want to know.

I think it is:
[LegoFabuland Container, Side Bags / Saddlebags](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=749&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

Comment: ah true, I tagged it as piece-information and forgot the actual question